# Printer problem Canon Pixma MG2570 in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers, printing, canon

The printer comes with windows drivers only so I downloaded the Linux driver here:

http://support-sg.canon-asia.com/contents/SG/EN/0100550201.html

When I run

> sudo bash install.sh

I got the following error message:

> Command executed = sudo /usr/sbin/lpadmin -p MG2500 -m canonmg2500.ppd -v
>
> cnijbe://Canon/?port=usb&serial=B3FABF -E
>
> lpadmin: Unable to copy PPD file.
>
> The printer registration has not been completed.
>
> Register the printer manually by using the lpadmin command.

The printer can be recognized, but no response when I tried to print something.

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: i wonder if this is the only usb printer connected to this computer

Comment: @pdc Yes, I have one printer only.

Comment: I'd forget the default script; the .PPD file you need I can see in your pasted error messages which is the only file you need. Just use Ubuntu printer setup and select "i have ppd file" & point it to that ppd file.  (note: i hate printer setup & forget whatever I did the millisec after it worked ... you may need to refer to https://askubuntu.com/questions/843895/install-printer-using-custom-ppd-file-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download the ppd file here:

https://github.com/liberodark/Print-PPD/blob/master/Canon/canon-mg2500.ppd.gz

Then choose "property", change the "manufacturer and model number". Then choose the option "provide ppd file".

My printer can print properly now

Comment: Where are you "choosing" these properties? In the printer dialog? In the command line?